# Why is the first footnotemark symbol (asterisk) missing?

Tags: footnotes

The following MWE should demonstrate the problem. My platform: Lualatex (Win32/64 with TL2016, both with current updates).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}% without this, everything seems to work fine
%\setmainfont{Arial}% the same here

\usepackage[%
    main=english,
]{babel}%

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\chapter{Symbolic footnotes and Times New Roman or Arial}

First footnote\footnote{Hello World!}\\
Second footnote\footnote{Hello Again!}\\
Third footnote\footnote{Heeeeello Agaiiiiiinn!}

\bigskip

Question(s):

When I use TNR or Arial font for example, the first footnotemark symbol (asterisk) is missing. Why?
(Note: Using Latin Modern, the output is fine.)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\DeclareTextSymbol{\textasteriskcentered}\UnicodeEncodingName{"002A}` -- This should be fixed by the LaTeX-Team

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Works fine. Thanks a lot. As I would like to remove this workaround as soon as possible, I've two additional questions: Is the Latex-Team already aware of this. If so, where can I track the progress?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel actually it's not so clear what the fix should be

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's just a quick and dirty solution. However I think there should be a more general solution.

Comment: Thanks for the report, This is now fixed in the base LaTeX release.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've updated my TL2016, the asterisk looks fine, but now e.g. \d e does not compile any more (has this something to do with your modifications? (see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355235/how-to-place-a-dot-below-for-example-e)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

In the 2017/01/01 Patch Level 2 release of LaTeX (which is today's texlive update) The document as posted in the question works without missing footnotes.

---

**Original Answer**

You will have a warning in the log

```
Missing character: There is no ∗ (U+2217) in font TimesNewRoman:mode=node;scri
pt=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
```

or if you have an earlier version of `tuenc.def` (U+294E)

You could use `*` (U+002A) which is available in all fonts but is a superscript asterisk.

so one of these:

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textasteriskcentered}{TU}{"204E} [⁎] [LOW ASTERISK]

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textasteriskcentered}{TU}{"2217}%  [∗] [ASTERISK OPERATOR]

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textasteriskcentered}{TU}{"002A}% [*] [ASTERISK]
```

The tricky thing is to find a setup that works in all fonts, and gives a low asterisk.

Possibly as a default we will use

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{TU}{%
  \iffontchar\font"2217 \char"2217 \else\raisebox{-.5ex}{*}\fi}
```

---

Current plan (in svn sources for the next release) is as below, but may adjust it a bit more before release.

```
%    \end{macrocode}
% Not all fonts have U+2217 but using U+002A requires some adjustment.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}\UnicodeEncodingName{%
  \iffontchar\font"2217 \char"2217 \else
    \begingroup
      \fontsize
       {\the\dimexpr1.2\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
       {\f@baselineskip}%
      \selectfont 
      \raisebox{-0.6ex}[\dimexpr\height-0.6ex][0pt]{*}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
%    \end{macrocode}
```

Comment: your generic answer seems very interesting and helpful to me, as I also use commercial fonts others might not have access to and thus cannot help I need to be able to solve this problem by my own (thanks). Nevertheless I currently don't know which answer is more acceptable. Need to think about it.

Comment: @lAtExFaN we will probably do some test for the character on the next release I was just chatting with other team members here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35384419#35384419 and suggested similar to I see egreg just answered

Comment: @lAtExFaN updated with a possible definition

Answer (score 7):

With the current TU default encoding, `\textasteriskcentered` is mapped to U+2217 ASTERISK OPERATOR which Times New Roman happens to miss.

The old EU1/EU2 encodings are based on `xunicode` that mapped `\textasteriskcentered` to U+002A ASTERISK, which was the wrong thing to do, since the output when used as a footnote marker is definitely bad:

[image]

Compare with the output we get with TeX Gyre Termes

[image]

If I add

```
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{TU}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{%
  \iffontchar\font"2217 \char"2217 \else\loweredasterisk\fi
}
\newcommand\loweredasterisk{\raisebox{-.5ex}{*}}
```

to the preamble, I get, with Times New Roman,

[image]

which is still not very good, but definitely better than the previous output.

An altogether different solution: use TeX Gyre Termes for the symbol. You could also add code for coping with different font families.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[
    main=english,
]{babel}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\termes}{TeX Gyre Termes}% for the asterisk

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fnsymbol}
  {\textasteriskcentered}
  {{\termes\textasteriskcentered}}
  {}{\ddt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\chapter{Symbolic footnotes and Times New Roman or Arial}

First footnote\footnote{Hello World!}\\
Second footnote\footnote{Hello Again!}\\
Third footnote\footnote{Heeeeello Agaiiiiiinn!}

\bigskip

Question(s):

When I use TNR or Arial font for example, the first footnotemark symbol (asterisk) is missing. Why?
(Note: Using Latin Modern, the output is fine.)

\end{document}
```

[image]