# How to place a dot below for example: e?

Tags: errors, luatex, accents, characters, bugs

After I updated my TL2016 (Windows) environment (10 minutes ago) compiling documents containing for example `\d{e}` or `\d e` throws an error message. The following MWE should demonstrate this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[%
main=english,
]{babel}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{How to place a dot below for example: e?}

\d e

The command throws the error messages:\\
Extra \textbackslash{}else. \textbackslash{}d e\\
Extra \textbackslash{}fi. \textbackslash{}d e

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes I've just seen it. Thanks a lot for the workaround and the hint regarding the edit

Comment: Update will have to be tomorrow now, I need to decide what to do about http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355251/1090

Comment: @Mico: I don't understand the sense behind the bounty - what else do you expect? Or has it something to do with your question (linked in david's comment)?

Comment: @1AtExFaN - The stated purpose, or "sense", of the bounty is "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."

Comment: @Mico: ah, that obviously makes sense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Line 84 of `latex/base/tuenc.def` is

```
  \relax\detokenize{#2}^^a0\else#2\fi
```

Please edit to say

```
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax^^a0\else#2\fi
```

I'll get an update to the release this evening, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my TL2016 installation today and recompiled the above MWE: The error has gone.

The error was caused by a bug in the latex-base package and has been fixed in the 2017/01/01 PL 3 Release (published 2017/02/22)

Details see changelog:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/changes.txt

Comment: sorry about that:-)

Comment: Sorry? No man, thank you very much for the fast solution!